# Using CrudRepository interface to auto-implement methods that return different type of objects

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to convert a Spring MVC application into a combo of Spring REST + Angular2 app.This is my 'Ticket.java' entity class (skipped getters and setters)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ticket")
public class Ticket {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="bookings_id")
private Booking booking;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="customer_id")
private Customer customer;

@Column(name="seat_no")
private int seatNumber;



public Ticket(){

}
```

How do I write a method in TicketDAO that returns all the customers given the booking.id? Here is the TicketDAO.java interface

```
  public interface TicketDAO extends CrudRepository<Ticket, Integer>{

    // I want to auto-implement such type of method using CrudRepository
//  public List<Customer>  getCustomersBooking(int bId);    }
```

I have previously implemented such method as :

```
@Override
    public List<Customer> getCustomersBooking(int bId) {


      Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        logger.info("DAOgetCustomersBooking: D1");
      List<Customer>  customer = new ArrayList<Customer>();

        Query<Ticket> theQuery =
                currentSession.createQuery("from Ticket where bookings_id = "+bId, Ticket.class);

        List<Ticket>  tickets = theQuery.getResultList();
            for (Ticket temp: tickets){
                customer.add(temp.getCustomer());
                }

        return customer;
    }
```

But now I want to auto-implement such type of method using CrudRepository in the TicketDAO interface. How will I write a method declaration that will enable me to do so?

For Reference, Booking.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="bookings")
public class Booking {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="van_id")
    private Van van;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="driver_id")
    private Driver driver;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="route_id")
    private Route route;

    @Column(name="registered_seats")
    private int registeredSeats;

    @Column(name="departure_time")
    private String departureTime;
    @Column(name="arival_time")
    private String arrivalTime;
    @Column(name="departure_date")
    private String departureDate;



    @Column(name="expected_price")
    private int expectedPrice;

    //Ticket.java   reference
     @OneToMany(mappedBy="booking",fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     private Set<Ticket> tickets;


    //Webdata.java   reference
         @OneToOne(mappedBy="bookingWebdata",fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
            private Webdata webdata;
```

Customers.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="regnumber")
    private int regNumber;

    @Column(name="phonenumber")
    private int phoneNumber;

    @Column(name="flagged")
    private int flagged;


    //Ticket.java   reference
         @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
         private Set<Ticket> tickets;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for a project I used JpaRepository but I think that's the same kind of request.

You have to use @Query() with HQL based on your java entities.

I gave object directly in the request and not the id so I don't know if you can do with id as I do with object. 
Like this :

```
public interface TicketDAO extends CrudRepository<Ticket, Integer>{

    @Query("SELECT t.customer FROM Ticket t WHERE t.booking = ?1")
    public List<Customer>  getCustomersBooking(Booking booking);    
}
```

If you want to try with id, it would be around that :

```
public interface TicketDAO extends CrudRepository<Ticket, Integer>{

    @Query("SELECT t.customer FROM Ticket t WHERE t.booking.id = ?1")
    public List<Customer>  getCustomersBooking(int bId);    
}
```